# How to sort csv by specific column

Tags: bash, shell, csv, sorting

I try to sort a csv contain temperatures by the 4th column.

```
Sort -n -k4 temperature.csv
```

As a result I get this:

```
2017-06-24 11:20,23.57,19.0,16.7,0.087,3.615
2017-06-24 11:25,23.51,19.0,16.7,0.087,3.689
2017-06-24 12:45,22.03,19.0,17.1,0.096,4.152
2017-06-24 13:00,21.92,19.0,17.1,0.096,4.229
2017-06-24 14:00,22.22,19.0,17.4,0.197,4.639
2017-06-24 14:25,22.21,19.0,17.5,0.197,4.774
2017-06-24 15:10,22.30,19.0,17.1,0.134,5.472
2017-06-24 16:00,22.42,19.0,17.3,0.134,5.93
2017-06-24 17:45,22.07,21.0,17.0,0.144,6.472
2017-06-24 18:25,21.90,21.0,16.9,0.15,6.814
2017-06-24 19:40,23.01,21.0,16.9,0.318,8.503
```

As you can see the 4th column isn't sorted correctly. I would expect 17.5 in tbe first line and 16.7 in the last line.

I also tried this:

```
sort -n -t. -k4,1n temperature.csv
```

The result is exactly the same as the previous example.
Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following `sort` command:

```
sort -t, -k4,4 -nr temperature.csv
```

The output:

```
2017-06-24 14:25,22.21,19.0,17.5,0.197,4.774
2017-06-24 14:00,22.22,19.0,17.4,0.197,4.639
2017-06-24 16:00,22.42,19.0,17.3,0.134,5.93
2017-06-24 15:10,22.30,19.0,17.1,0.134,5.472
2017-06-24 13:00,21.92,19.0,17.1,0.096,4.229
2017-06-24 12:45,22.03,19.0,17.1,0.096,4.152
2017-06-24 17:45,22.07,21.0,17.0,0.144,6.472
2017-06-24 19:40,23.01,21.0,16.9,0.318,8.503
2017-06-24 18:25,21.90,21.0,16.9,0.15,6.814
2017-06-24 11:25,23.51,19.0,16.7,0.087,3.689
2017-06-24 11:20,23.57,19.0,16.7,0.087,3.615
```

---

- `-t,` - field delimiter
- `-k4,4` - sort by 4th field only
- `-nr` - sort numerically in reverse order

Comment: A correct, useful answer (+1) but you could mention that `sort` can fail if the data file contains `"quoted strings, that may contain commas (or even newlines)"`.  A more general solution should involve the parsing of the data.

Comment: @gboffi, for ideal and complex inputs there would be another complex solution. For the current input, simple `sort` will do the job

Answer (score 1):

While the `sort` command has some hacks to partially handle CSV files, it won't handle all CSV format features. [`csvsort`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvsort.html?highlight=csvsort) is a great option:

```bash
csvsort -c 4 temperature.csv
```

Comment: Good. This is what I need.