# Unix: Sort 'ls' by return value of program

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

how can I use program as a key to sort in Unix shell? In other words to sort output of 'ls' (or any other program) by return value of a program applied on each line.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: The question (sort by a manually defined order) is very interesting. However, the way it is formulated right now will probably result in lots of comments of the form "*`don't parse ls`", "`XY problem`", "`needs more details`"*. I suggest to edit the question to focus on *"`sort by a manually defined order`"* (this order can come from `ls`, but doesn't have to). Then, give more details, for instance, how should elements be sorted when they are not in the custom order?

Comment: And tell more about the program. Is it like `compare string1 string2` returning -1, 0 or 1 or is het a complete sorting program (like `sort`)? In the last situation you can use something like `ls | mysortingprogram`.

Comment: I want to sort the file list by i-node number. The program takes a name of file and returns inode. I have to use this program for that (it's a homework).

Comment: ls -i1 | sort. 
'ls -i1' shows each file's inode with 1 col of output, and 'sort' does, well, sort

Comment: I opened a separate question to cover sorting based on an external command, that is worthwhile thing to cover in my opinion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837691/how-to-sort-strings-depending-on-the-output-value-of-a-program/61837692#61837692

Answer (score 0):

I'll give two example solutions:

1. A one-line command that is simpler and therefore something I'd try use first.
2. A bash script that allows sorting a list by output from an arbitrary bash function that reads each line of the list as input.

### Example 1 (without executing command on each line)

If the question is how to, in general, sort outputs of programs like `ls`, below is an example specific to `ls` that sorts by inode. However, every program may have its own idiosyncrasies when generating its output so this example may have to be adapted:

```
ls -ail /home/user/ | tail -n+2 | tr -s ' ' | sort -t' ' -k1,1 -g
```

Here are the different parts of this command broken down:

```
ls -ail /home/user/
```

Lists all (`-a`) files in directory /home/user/ in list (`-l`) format with inode (`-i`).

```
tail -n+1
```

Cuts off first line from ls output.

```
tr -s ' '
```

Combines (`-s`) multiple spaces (`' '`) for `sort`.

```
sort -t ' ' -k 1 -g
```

Sorts list by first (`1`) field of integers (`-g`) separated by one space (`' '`).

### Example 2 (executing command with each line as input)

Here is a more adaptable example in a bash script I worked up to show how the list of files generated from `ls -a1` can be fed into bash function `getinode` which uses `stat` to output the inode for each file. A while loop repeats this process for each file, saving in comma-delimited format the data by repeatedly appending a variable named `OUTPUT` which at the end is sorted by `sort` using the first field.

The important part is that the function `getinode` can be anything, so long as it outputs a string. I set up `getinode` to receive a file path as input (first argument `$1`) and to then output the inode to stdout via `echo $INODE`. The script calls `getinode` via `$(getinode "$FILEPATH")`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: lsinodesort.sh [file]
# Refs/attrib:
#   [1]: How to sort a csv file by sorting on a single field. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44744800
#   [2]: How to read a while loop variable. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16854326

WORKDIR="$1" # read directory from first argument

getinode() {
    # Usage: getinode [path]
    INODE="$(stat "$1" --format=%i)"
    echo $INODE
}

if [ -d "$WORKDIR" ]; then
    LINES="$(ls -a1 "$WORKDIR")" # save `ls` output to variable LINES
else
    exit 1; # not a valid directory
fi

while read line; do
    path="$WORKDIR"/"$line" # Determine path.
    if [ -f "$path" ]; then # Check if path is a file.
    FILEPATH="$path"
    FILENAME="$(basename "$path")" # Determine filename from path.
    FILEINODE=$(getinode "$FILEPATH") # Get inode.
    OUTPUT="$FILEINODE"",""$FILENAME""\n""$OUTPUT" ; # Append inode and file name to OUTPUT
    fi
done <<< "$LINES"  # See [2].

OUTPUT=$(printf "${OUTPUT}" | sort -t, -k1,1) # sort OUTPUT. See [1]
OUTPUT="inode","filename""\n""$OUTPUT"
printf "${OUTPUT}\n" # print final OUTPUT.
```

When I run it on my own home folder I get output like this:

```
inode,filename
3932162,.bashrc
3932165,.bash_logout
3932382,.zshrc
3932454,.gitconfig
3933234,.bash_aliases
3933512,.profile
3933612,.viminfo
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure to understand your question, so I'll try to rephrase it first.
If I'm not mistaken, you want to sort the output of a program (it may be ls or any other command in a Unix shell).
I'll suggest using the pipeline feature available on Unix shell.
For instance, you can sort the output of the ls command using :

```
ls /home | sort
```

This feature is available but not limited to the ls command.
By the way, there are optional flags you can use for sorting ls command results if that's your specific use case :

```
ls -S # for sorting by file size
ls -t # for sorting by modification time
```

You can also append the `--reverse` or `-r` flag for displaying the result in reverse order.

As for the `sort` function, there are also flags allowing to customize your result as per your needs :

```
sort -n # for sorting numerically instead of alphabetically
sort -k5 # for sorting based on the 5th column
sort -t "," # for using the comma as a field separator
```

You can combine all of them like that for sorting the output of ‘ls -l‘ command on the basis of field 2,5 (Numeric) and 9 (Non-Numeric/alphabetically).

```
ls -l /home/$USER | sort -t "," -nk2,5 -k9
```

[sort function examples](https://www.tecmint.com/sort-command-linux/)